# CKEditor no keyboard on Android

Tags: android, keyboard, ckeditor

When I tested my site on Android phone I have noticed that I can't edit content in CKEditor, the keyboard does not appear.

I have testes on iPad, Android Tablet, all works, but not on phone. BTW, I have tested standard browser and Dolphin too, problem in both.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show the keyboard by keeping the menu button pressed for a little longer.

Comment: Yes, I can, but it's not convenient for web-site visitors. Maybe exist some explanation of this issue?